# Will 14.5 v @ 2.0 Amps harm my MacBook 12

Tags: laptop, usb, power-supply, macbook, battery

I'd like to charge my MacBook 12 using my PowerBank. I have a PowerBank with adjustable voltage control it has USB output too. Though when I use USB output it draws only 0.5A @ 4.75V on average and reports that the "battery is not charging". I've also noticed that my Apple 29W USB-C PowerAdapter supports two output modes 5.2V @ 2.4A and 14.5V @ 2.0A. I was reading through the internet about second delivery option and it seems that it has something to do with USB PowerDelivery specification. I'm not quite sure what it is and how to make my PowerBank to support one. But my question is the following. If I were to setup my PowerBank to supply 14.5V @ 2.0A instead of 5.0V @ 2.4A, will it harm my MacBook?

---

**Edit**

Ok, I've tried it with 14.5V @ 2.0A it was drawing 14.5V @ 0.45A, still it didn't want to charge the battery, so seems that something additional is required to make that happen with my PowerBank. The question remains open.

**P.S.**

Notebook operates normally with standard Apple Charger after that 14.5V @ 2.0A test.

Any thoughts on how to make it charge my laptop with such kind of power bank?

Comment: Hmm... 0.45A. Sounds like the power bank isn't communicating with the laptop. I'd probably get a power bank that's actually designed to charge the MacBook.

Comment: What kind of "USB output" does your PowerBank have? Is it "Type-C", or regular "Type-A"?

Comment: It's Type-A, but also device carries several other outlets (9V/12V/20V). The 20V is adjustable from 12V ... 30V. So I was thinking about setting 14.5V on a 20V outlet, stripping one USB-C wire and attaching it to that power output. It may sound funny but eventually it's the same electricity that is generated by Apple's power adapter. I just want to know what has to be done in order to make it draw available power at nominal 5.2V / 14.5V voltage.

Comment: There are a LOT of cowboy fake PD chargers out there that don't support the standard properly - and you should avoid. The website GTrusted.com have many such reviews - the only reliable one I've seen is the Anker 60W PowerPort+ USB C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your power bank doesn't comply with the [USB Power Delivery (USB-PD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_Power_Delivery_.28UPD.29) specification. However, as long as the voltage itself is within specification, it shouldn't cause any damage to your computer.

The 14.5V nominal output of the original Apple power supply is within the tolerances of the 15V output voltage specified in the standard. Any USB-PD compliant supply with a maximum output voltage of 14.5V/15V or 20V and maximum power of at least 29 watts should work (a USB-PD supply with higher output voltage or wattage must also support lower outputs). If your MacBook isn't charging, it means that your power bank isn't communicating with the laptop as required by the USB-PD specification.

More information about MacBook charging can be found in [this Apple article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204360). It states:

> Your MacBook will charge from USB-C power adapters not manufactured by Apple if they adhere to the USB Power Delivery specification.

---

Your most recent comment indicates that your power bank is merely acting as a dumb 14.5V power source. That won't work unless you have something to do the USB-PD handshaking between the source and laptop. I'd recommend getting a power bank that actually supports USB-PD at the required voltage and power levels. May I suggest the [Anker PowerCore Speed 20000 PD](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K6S29FE)? (*No affiliation, just a satisfied Anker user* .)